# popen2("unix") not working in octave

Tags: octave

I'm trying to get octave to execute a 2-way sub-process, in order to communicate with the shell 'online', while processing data acquired from the shell.

the normal `popen` is not good for me because it waits for the sub-process to return before i'm able to process the data. 
So I tried all kinds of ways, and I've read the octave example for using `popen2("sort")`, but it didn't help me to get `popen2("unix")` working.

The error I get is:

> error: popen2: popen2 (child): unable to start process -- No such file or directory*

I get this error for other popen2 commands such as `popen2("help")`. Maybe I'm missing something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

```
error: popen2: popen2 (child): unable to start process -- No such file or directory*
```

tries to tell you, that there is no command or program "unix". Which OS are you using and why are you expecting that there is a command "unix" available? Btw, have you had a look at system?

If you really want a two way communication with a shell try

```
[in, out, pid] = popen2 ("bash");
```

Comment: I mistakenly thought that "sort", in this context, was an octave command, and therefore tried  "unix" as it is also an octave command. But popen2 expects system commands...